# Deploying an external assembly (DevExpress) to an azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, assemblies, kudu

We are deploying to azure automatically from github via a kudu script.  It was working okay until I tried to add DevExpress XtraReports to a project.

I have some DevExpress references in my csproj file like so:

```
<Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraReports.v16.2, Version=16.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\Resources\DevExpress.XtraReports.v16.2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Everything run great and works fine on my local machine but when it builds on azure I get the following error: "The type or namespace name 'DevExpress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".  The DevExpress dlls are checkin into source control and are set to copy local true.

All the packages that are nuget packages work fine.  However DevExpress has to be a binary reference and I am not sure how to copy them to the correct directory to be included when everything builds in azure.

Thoughts?  I feel like I am missing something obvious but cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: Fwiw, this should "just work", I have done this on a few projects. I'd start by checking all your assumptions; use scm to check that the file is in the repo on Azure, try doing a clean checkout on your own machine to try it etc.

Comment: @Frans See my answer.  I am embarrassed to say it but it was the typical files aren't in source control error.  (sigh.)

Comment: We've all been there ;)

Answer (score 1):

This was egg on my face, ID10T error, whatever you want to call it.  It was the typical the files weren't in source control error.  While working late at night I saw the *.xml files in source control and *assumed* it was the dll files.  With fresh eyes I caught it.  It was driving me crazy.

Comment: That would do it. :) In https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Make-sure-site-correctly-deploys-locally, I suggest always testing locally from a clean clone of the repo to eliminate those possibilities.

Comment: @DavidEbbo that is a good suggestion and I am going to starting testing locally now.